# Other than speed (I'm assuming)- what am I losing if I install Elementary OS on HDD?

Tags: system-installation

I ask only because I don't have a spare SSD and don't want to dual-boot.

Comment: Nothing else. elementary works fine either way

Comment: losing compared to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely nothing. Even gaming changes mainly in loading times (of well optimized). 
I would say apart from the starting and shutdown times you won't notice the difference